# How can I use contains method with custom arraylist?

Tags: java

How can I use [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method to search by id only, I want to check if there is id equal 4 or not without using loop, How?

**Test Class**

```
public class Test {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Test(int id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

**Set Data**

```
List <Test> list = new ArrayList <> ();
list.add(new Test(1, "Name 1", 25));
list.add(new Test(2, "Name 2", 37));
list.add(new Test(3, "Name 3", 63));
list.add(new Test(4, "Name 4", 19));
list.add(new Test(5, "Name 5", 56));
```

Comment: You can store your classes in a map, where id is the key. But for a list you cannot avoid iterating over it.

Comment: Can you try using JSON without creating POJO class.

Answer (score 6):

If you check the contains method from java library. It internally calls `indexOf` method (which internally calls `indexOfRange` method), it return the index by making the `equals` method call on object.

```
int indexOfRange(Object o, int start, int end) {
        Object[] es = elementData;
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (es[i] == null) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (o.equals(es[i])) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

In your code `equals` will be called on `Test` class object.

As the solution either override the `equals` method to return `true`, if `id` matched. **But I would say that won't be a good solution because `equals` method should follow some contracts.**

So alternatively correct should be use of `Streams` API here (although Stream also will use iteration internally).

```
List <Test> list = new ArrayList <> ();
list.add(new Test(1, "Name 1", 25));
list.add(new Test(2, "Name 2", 37));
list.add(new Test(3, "Name 3", 63));
list.add(new Test(4, "Name 4", 19));
list.add(new Test(5, "Name 5", 56));
        
boolean isMatch = arr.stream().anyMatch(i-> i.id == toMatch);
```

Comment: Yes, overriding `equals` sounds more intuitive (but as Gaurav says, it should follow some contract and logic) as that would mean there is a basis for comparison between any two objects. Also keep in mind that it is a best practice approach that if you override `equals` then it makes sense to override `hashCode` as well.

Comment: `.stream` added in API 24 in android and minSdkVersion in my android app is API 23, So there is no another way?

Comment: you can write a user defined function and can return . Using normal for loop / itetor. But you need to iterate the entire list until match is found. Ref :https://www.baeldung.com/find-list-element-java